Calculating Pore Size from Permeability
I am building an experiment where one has a bed of sand on top of a porous plate.  The pores allow air to be blown through the plate from the bottom but the pores must be sufficiently fine to not allow sand to fall back through.
The sand grains will probably have diameters ranging between 20 and 60 $\mu m$ and the permeability of the plate is $3 \times 10^{-13} \: \text{m}^2$.  How does one estimate the pore size from this?
I checked online and it seems the relevant relation is the Kozeny equation for absolute permeability:
$\kappa = \Phi_s^2 \frac{\epsilon^3 d_p^2}{180 (1 - \epsilon)^2},$
where $\Phi_s$ is the sphericity of the particles in the sand bed, $\epsilon$ is the porosity, and $d_p$ is the diameter of the volume equivalent spherical particle.  $\kappa$ is the absolute permeability.  Is this the correct equation for determining the pore size of the plate?

Do you know how to determine the equivalent equation for a useries of parallel circular pores oriented in the direction of flow?

No, not sure.  Is this Darcy flow?

No.  Are you familiar with this Hagen Poiseuille law for viscous flow in a tube?

But this equation has a pressure difference in it?

Poiseullle's law for a single tube and Ergun equation for a packed bed both have pressure differences.
